# In Matlab, how to specify number of digits in the exponent using formatSpec formatting operator?

Tags: matlab, printf, precision, exponent

I'm writing data to an output text file using the `fprintf` command in Matlab. How to write a number to the output file, for instance, `1.12345678e-001`, **with three digits in the exponent**?

```
formatSpec = '%1.8e\n';
```

gives `1.12345678e-01`, not the desired result!

There's a similar question here
https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100772-how-do-i-use-fprintf-to-write-numbers-in-exponential-notation-of-variable-exponent-digits-on-a-windo

But following the instructions given there didn't solve the problem!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this non-regex method:

```
num = 0.112345678
pow = floor(log10(abs(num)));
sprintf('%.8fe%+.3d', num/10^pow, pow)

ans =
1.12345678e-001
```

For multiple inputs use this:

```
num= [.123 .456 .789];
pow = floor(log10(abs(num)));
sprintf('%.8fe%+.3d ', [num./10.^pow; pow])
```

Comment: Nice.  I like this solution better than mine.

Comment: @rahnema1 may be little silly question,  if `num= [.123; .456; .789];` how can I format the output data in rows instead of columns? I have multiple one column arrays of double data type e.g. `x = [-0.00912036467;-0.00838289689;-0.0106730480;-0.0115961293;-0.00669082161;...]` that need to be changed to the format `x = [-9.12036467e-003; -8.38289689e-003; -1.06730480e-002; -1.15961293e-002; -6.69082161e-003;...]`

Comment: @Emma  You could just modify the last  line to add new line instead of a space 
 `sprintf('%.8fe%+.3d\n', [num./10.^pow; pow])`

Comment: @Emma Sorry for late reply. Sice the array is a column vector you should first transpose it. As AeroEngy pointed out you can use `\n` instead of space. `x = x.';pow = floor(log10(abs(x)));sprintf('%.8fe%+.3d\n', [x ./ 10 .^pow; pow]);`

Comment: @Aero Engy that does not really give correct values, you can try it!

I have solved the issue by employing for-loop and empty cell array, and wrote the result to the output file line by line :
`num = [.123; .456; .789]
j = cell(size(num))
pow = floor(log10(abs(num))),
n = num./10.^pow,
for i=1:length(n)
j{i,:} =sprintf('%.8fe%+.3d', n(i,:),pow(i,:))
end

j = 
    '1.23000000e-001'
    '4.56000000e-001'
    '7.89000000e-001'
`
For output:
`formatSpec = '%s';
for i=1:length(num)
fprintf(fileIDout,formatSpec,j{i,:});
end`

Comment: No need to loop. This should work: `num= [.123; .456; .789];num = num.';pow = floor(log10(abs(num)));fprintf(fileIDout,'%.8fe%+.3d\n', [num./10 .^pow; pow])`

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this falls under the category of *solution* or *work-around*, but here it goes:

```
x = .123e25; % example number
formatSpec = '%1.8e\n'; % format specification
s = sprintf(formatSpec, x); % "normal" sprintf
pat = '(?<=e)[+-]\d+'; % regex pattern to detect exponent
s = regexprep(s, pat, sprintf('%+04i', str2double(regexp(s, pat ,'match')))); % zero-pad
```

It uses regular expressions to identify the exponent substring and replace it with the exponent zero-padded to three digits. Positive exponents include a plus sign, as with `fprintf`.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't the cleanest answer but you could do something like this.  Basic steps are write as is, get the exponent with a regexp, re-write that portion, and replace.

```
formatSpec = '%1.8e'

tempStr = sprintf(formatSpec,1.12345678e-1);
oldExp  = regexp(tempStr,'e[+-]([0-9]+)$','tokens');
newExp  = num2str(str2double(oldExp{1}{1}),'%03d');
fixedStr = regexprep(tempStr,[oldExp{1}{1} '$'],newExp)
```

This outputs:

```
fixedStr =    
1.12345678e-001
```

Comment: Well, it's probably cleaner than mine :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo I started to do something like yours but the nested regexp inside of the regexprep where killing me.  I did like your use of 'match' with the `(?<=e) look behind operator